# What do the words 'Dhatu,' 'Moola,' and 'Jeeva' mean in Vedic astrology?

Tags: vedas, astrology, terminology, meaning, words

What do the words 'Dhatu,' 'Moola,' and 'Jeeva' mean in Vedic astrology?

Answer (score 2):

[Pandit Gopesh Kumar Ohja](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Predictive_Astrology_of_the_Hindus/ZxzkDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=moola%20jeeva%20dhatu&pg=PA82&printsec=frontcover) writes:

> ﻿It has been told already that in Hindu astrology all articles are divided into three categories: (i) inanimate matter-minerals, metals, etc., are covered by the term *Dhatu*; (ii) plants, trees, grass, creepers are covered by the term *Moola*; (iii) animate creation down from an insect to humans are called *Jeeva* (with life).
>
> The Sun and Mars preside over Dhatus. The Moon and Saturn have sway over Moola, while Jupiter and Venus represent Jeeva, Mercury has a mixed portfolio of all the three.

So: *Dhatu* is that which  is not alive, *Moola* is that which is alive but not human, and *Jeeva* is that which is alive and human.

Comment: Your answer is very useful.

Comment: @daiweisc - thank you, I hope it answers your question fully!